# Show geospatial TIFF as base layer in OpenLayers using GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to show a GeoSpatial TIFF file as a base layer in OpenLayers, on which further layers can be imposed.

Upon trying to add the TIFF file as GeoTIFF store GeoServer throws below error:

Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them:

`Failed to create reader from file:data/Sample.tif and hints Hints: REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@30c5d9f7 EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@45cb6ccc[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] System defaults: FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http FEATURE_FACTORY = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@3cc41abc LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory TILE_ENCODING = null STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl`

I tried to add the TIFF as ImageMossaic as well, but GeoServer gave below error:

Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them:

`Failed to create reader from file:data and hints Hints: REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@30c5d9f7 EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@45cb6ccc[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] System defaults: FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http FEATURE_FACTORY = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@3cc41abc LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory TILE_ENCODING = null STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl`

I have hundreds of continuous Geospatial TIFF images which shall be visible in OpenLayers according to the current position.

Any pointers/suggestions will help. Please suggest if I need to revise my approach or try any other way.

Comment: If you have installed GeoServer with the default demo data you should have  working examples at http://localhost:8080/geoserver/nurc/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=nurc%3APk50095&bbox=347649.93086859107%2C5176214.082539256%2C370725.976428591%2C5196961.352859256&width=768&height=690&srs=EPSG%3A32633&format=application/openlayers and at http://localhost:8080/geoserver/nurc/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=nurc%3Amosaic&bbox=6.346%2C36.492%2C20.83%2C46.591&width=768&height=535&srs=EPSG%3A4326&format=application/openlayers

Comment: Following your suggestion I tried to save a store for Pk50095 from coverages/img_sample folder then Store was created for it. When I tried the same thing by copying Pk50095 file into Data_dir/data folder it did not work and gave me the similar error. I kept my Tiff files in Data_Dir/Data earlier. Is it required to keep the TIFF files in coverage/img_sample folder ?

Comment: I copied all files from img_sample into data_dir/data and I could create a store without an error. If I delete .tfw and .prj first then I get that error which seems to prove that GeoServer requires proper georeferencing. Perhaps there is some problem with the georeferencing of your Sample.tif image.

Comment: Ok Thanks ! I will also check with the supporting files for the Tiff and will try to create the store.